# Load balancer and serverless NEG isn't working

Tags: google-app-engine

I configured Google Cloud load balancer and serverless NEG to make my app engine work in static IP, but it's not working anyway. Here are the commands I used for configuration.

```
gcloud beta compute network-endpoint-groups create get-payqin-serverless-neg \
    --region=europe-west1 \
    --network-endpoint-type=SERVERLESS  \
    --app-engine-app

gcloud compute backend-services create get-payqin-backend-service \
--global

gcloud beta compute backend-services add-backend get-payqin-backend-service \
--global \
--network-endpoint-group=get-payqin-serverless-neg \
--network-endpoint-group-region=europe-west1

gcloud compute url-maps create get-payqin-url-map \
--default-service get-payqin-backend-service
```

All those commands were just copied from google cloud documentation, only minor changes with parameters, so I think nothing is wrong with these commands.

The project has only one default service in Google App Engine, and it was deployed in europe-west region. I found that europe-west region is same as europe-west1 region in GAE.

I checked the app deployed in GAE was surely working from browser. The load balancer surely has its static IP assigned in frontend, but "http://{ip}" on browser shows 404 error page!

I can't figure out what's wrong with my configuration.

Please help me with this one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: is your app GAE standard or flex? Is there a tutorial/link you are following?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. I finished the configuration. The purpose is to make load balancing IP accessible from the internet, and the IP is routed to GAE.

I had to change static IP from the global type to regional. And the region should be in the same region as GAE instance.

Comment: How do you change static IP type from global to regional? could you post how you solved it? or you just reserve new static IP with regional type?